# enable 'OK' button after filling input boxes

Tags: python, point-clouds, pysimplegui

I'm using a code that deals with cloud points. In the interface part, I'm want to enable the "OK" button only if the 2 boxes are filled.
this is how the interface looks like :

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3sR6.png

this is part of my code :

```py
def make_window(theme=Theme): 
    NAME_SIZE = 23

    def name(name):
        dots = NAME_SIZE-len(name)-2
        return sg.Text(name + ' ' + '•'*dots, size=(NAME_SIZE,1), justification='r',pad=(0,0), font='Courier 10')

    sg.theme(theme) # thème défini au début du code

    layout_l = [[name('CLOUD'), sg.HSep()],
                [sg.Text('Input cloud (las/laz)')],
                [sg.InputText(s=(40,1)), sg.FileBrowse()], # Permet d'aller chercher le nuage en input
                [sg.Text('Output folder')],
                [sg.InputText(s=(40,1)), sg.FolderBrowse()], # Indique le dossier de sortie              
                [name('Info input cloud'), sg.Checkbox('')],
                [name('Points per box'), sg.Spin(['1000000','10000000','15000000','50000000'], s=(15,2))],
                [name('Classification'), sg.Combo(['none','SMRF','CSF','PMF'], default_value = 'none', s=(15,2))],
                [name('Create HAG'), sg.Checkbox('')],                                 
                [name('Info output cloud'), sg.Checkbox('')],
                [name('-ProgressBar'), sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='h', s=(10,20), k='-PBAR_1-')],
                [sg.Text('')],   
                [sg.Text('')],             
                [sg.Text('')]]

    layout_r  = [[name('RASTER'), sg.HSep()],
                [name('Type of cloud'), sg.Combo(['DIMORPH','MMS','FARO','VIAMETRIS'], default_value = 'DIMORPH', s=(15,22))],
                [name('Raster GS'), sg.Checkbox('')],
                [name('Raster RGB'), sg.Checkbox('')],
                [name('Raster Elevation GS'), sg.Checkbox('')],
                [name('Raster Elevation RGB'), sg.Checkbox('')],                
                [name('Raster HAG'), sg.Checkbox('')],
                [name('-ProgressBar'), sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='h', s=(10,20), k='-PBAR_2-')],
                [sg.Text('')], 
                [sg.Text('')],                
                [name('Preview'), sg.HSep()],
                [name('Preview'), sg.Checkbox('')],  
                [sg.Text('')],                                                                                     
                [sg.Button('OK', disabled=True,k='-OK-'), sg.Cancel()]] # Lance le traitement                                                                        

    layout = [[sg.T('Traitement de nuage de points', font='_ 18', justification='c', expand_x=True)],
              [sg.Col(layout_l), sg.Col(layout_r)]] # Compile les 2 fenêtre définies au dessus

    window = sg.Window('Programme CBR', layout, finalize=True, right_click_menu=sg.MENU_RIGHT_CLICK_EDITME_VER_EXIT, keep_on_top=True, use_custom_titlebar=use_custom_titlebar)

    window['-PBAR_1-'].update(0)
    window['-PBAR_2-'].update(0) 

    return window


window = make_window()

while True: # Tant que le GUI est affiché

    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'): # On peut en sortir avec Cancel
        break

    if values and values[1]  and values[2]:
        window['-OK-'].update(disabled=False)
        window.refresh()

    window['-PBAR_1-'].update(5)
```

knowing that `value[1]` and `values[2]` is for what in the boxes

I'm trying to enable "OK" button after filling the cloud and folder boxes

Answer (score 0):

In your event loop, execution will be wait here.

```py
event, values = window.read()
```

So you need event generated to execute the code after the `read` statement.

Set option `enable_events=True` for your `Input` elements, then changes to these elements are immediately reported as an event.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(enable_events=True, key='IN 1')],
    [sg.Input(enable_events=True, key='IN 2')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('OK', disabled=True)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ('IN 1', 'IN 2'):
        window['OK'].update(disabled=not(values['IN 1'] and values['IN 2']))

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, that was somewhat helpful. However, after filling in both inputs, the OK button not only get  activated, but also triggers. Did I miss something?

Comment: I cannot guess what happened if say nothing about the situation. Most of cases, your code is different from mine.